# Displaying array-responses in the form of a Nested menus using React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm fairly new to React and stuck regarding a very minor problem. I wrote an UI that essentially calls a service that returns the responses in the form of an array. Now, I need those responses from the service to be displayed in the form of a nested menu. For e. g., one of my axios calls returns a response of [1,2,3,4] and the other axios call returns [1.1,1.2,1.3,..]. I want these responses to be aligned in the form of

```
1
  1.1
  1.2
  1.3
2
  2.1
```

etc.,
i. e. the UI should show 1,2,3,4 .. and when the user clicks on 1, then 1.1,1.2 etc. should be displayed.

I'm using React, material-ui's components and redux for this.
I have a function to do the above mentioned.. but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

```
handleMenuData() {
var applist = this.props.menuData;
    var appNames = [];
    var moduleNames = [];
    applist.forEach(app => {
      app.moduleNames.forEach(module => {
        try {
          return axios.get(
            'service url' + app.name + '/' + module,
          );
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }

      });
      appNames.push({
        name: app.name,
        moduleNames: moduleNames,
      });
      moduleNames = [];
    });
    this.setState({
      appNames: appNames,
    });
  }
```

and in my state,

```
this.state = {
      appList: [],
      appNames: [],
      moduleNames: [],
    };
```

app names are 1,2,3 and module names are 1.1,1.2 and I was thinking of using ListItemText component from material UI.

Comment: Hi, have you tried logging your state after the setState is done? In other words what result are you getting from your code?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure on how to do it.

Comment: In your `handleMenuData()` function, at the bottom just `console.log(this.state)`. You can also use the Chrome dev tools with the React extension to see the state changes in realtime.

Comment: Hi Keno, {appList: Array(0), appNames: Array(0), moduleNames: Array(0)} - I see this when I add console.log.

Comment: I'm guessing your 'service url' is an actual url in your code?

Comment: yes, its a call to the backend. I modified it to
    var applist = this.state.appList;
    var appNames = [];
    var moduleNames = [];
    applist.forEach(app => {
      app.moduleNames.forEach(module => {
        url =
          axios.get('service url') + module;
        moduleNames.push({ name: module });
      });
      url = axios.get('service url') + app.name;
      appNames.push({
        name: app.name,
        moduleNames: moduleNames,
      });
      moduleNames = [];
    });
    this.setState({
      appNames: appNames,
    });
    console.log(this.state);
  }

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing is incorrect. axios.get is an asynchronous function and you are not waiting for the response to come from the server. That's why you get all arrays as empty. Try calling a recursive function like this.

```
const getModuleNames = (i) => {
    axios.get('service url' + applist[i].name + '/' + module)
        .then((response) => {
           if(i < applist.length){ 
              applist[i].moduleNames = response.data;
              appNames.push({
                 name: applist[i].name,
                 moduleNames: applist[i].moduleNames
              });
              getModuleNames(i++);
            }
            else {
               // code you want to execute after adding data to appNames
            }
        }).catch((err) => {
            // error handling
        });
}

getModuleNames(0);
```